# Workbook_BeforeSave removed file types in Save As dialogue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master file accessed by multiple users that is used as a template on a monthly basis. I use the following code to to allow someone to *Save As*, but not *Save over* the Template. I also made it unable to run if "Template" is not found within the file name, so that the saved-as copies can be reopened and edited as needed. Here is that code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim strOrigFile As String
    strOrigFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Dim strNamePath As String
    Dim strWorkOrNot As Integer

    strWorkOrNot = InStr(1, strOrigFile, "Template")
    If strWorkOrNot = 0 Then GoTo AbortProcess

    If SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
        strNamePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

        Select Case strNamePath
        Case "False"
        Case strOrigFile
            MsgBox "It may be a bad idea to save over the template. You should use Save-As and create a new file.", vbCritical, "Avoid Corrupting the Template!"
        Case Else
            Application.EnableEvents = 0
            Me.SaveAs strNamePath
            Application.EnableEvents = 1
        End Select
    Else
        If ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name = strOrigFile Then
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "It may be a bad idea to save over the template. You should use Save-As and create a new file.", vbCritical, "Avoid Corrupting the Template!"
        End If
    End If

AbortProcess:

End Sub
```

When a user *does* Save As however, the dialogue box does not give any file type options and if someone doesn't specify during the save it will create a file that is missing an extension.

How do I tweak this code to keep the Save As dialogue box from removing the file type options? And out of curiosity why is it doing that?

[Solved]

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim strOrigFile As String
    strOrigFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Dim strNamePath As String
    Dim strWorkOrNot As Integer

    strWorkOrNot = InStr(1, strOrigFile, "Template")
    If strWorkOrNot = 0 Then GoTo AbortProcess
    On Error GoTo SaveAsMacroWarning

    If SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = "New"
            .Show
            If "False" Then
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
            Else
                strNamePath = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With

        Select Case strNamePath
        Case strOrigFile
            MsgBox "It may be a bad idea to save over the template. You should use Save-As and create a new file.", vbCritical, "Avoid Corrupting the Template!"
        Case Else
            Application.EnableEvents = 0
            Me.SaveAs Filename:=strNamePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            Application.EnableEvents = 1
        End Select
    Else
        If ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name = strOrigFile Then
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "It may be a bad idea to save over the template. You should use Save-As and create a new file.", vbCritical, "Avoid Corrupting the Template!"
        End If
    End If

SaveAsMacroWarning:

    MsgBox "You'll need to save it as a Macro-Enabled file type.", vbCritical, "Save as Macro-Enabled"

AbortProcess:

End Sub
```

Comment: Why dont you check if strNamePath has the extension you need and if it does not add an extension to it in the code?

Comment: That's a thought... I work for a nonprofit that helps/employs adults with mental disabilities. I do my utmost to make the user experience as normal as possible to prevent triggering an episode. So I'd _really_ like to have the dialogue box and file type options they're used to. (The primary goal is protecting the template though so I will definitely consider that idea, thanks!)

Comment: Hi Ane, can the new files be restricted to .xlsx (without code)?

Comment: Hey PB! Long time no "see!" I'd need it to be .xlsm if anything. Do you have any theories of why it's doing that? Does cancelling the SaveAsUI destroy the defaults perhaps and do I actually need that in the code?

Comment: Hey pnuts! That rule drives me pnuts! It's so much easier to find the answers I need straight from Google with the tags in the title. I'm not a rebel by nature though so I'll obey in a passive aggressive but inwardly seething sort of way and cope with my emotions through humor. [Thanks](http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/srcstc.gif) for your contribution! (Eh? Not bad right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing default file types are caused by Application.**GetSaveAsFilename**()

Try using Application.**FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim fId As String, oldName As String, iniName As String, fn As String

    If SaveAsUI Then
        Cancel = True
        fId = " - " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
        oldName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        oldName = Left(oldName, InStrRev(oldName, ".") - 1)
        iniName = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, oldName, oldName & fId)

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = iniName
            .Show
            If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
                fn = .SelectedItems(1)
                fn = Right(fn, Len(fn) - InStrRev(fn, "\"))
                fn = Left(fn, InStrRev(fn, ".") - 1)
                If fn = oldName Then fn = Replace(.SelectedItems(1), fn, fn & fId)

                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Me.SaveAs fn
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As always thanks for your awesomeness Paul! I'm going to keep this as the front runner but still keep the question open just in case someone figures out how to get the file type option back on. I'll give it a week.

Comment: Good point! I updated the answer to replace GetSaveAsFilename with FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs); the code will force a new name even if the user insists on using the old name but you may want to use your initial warning :)

Comment: Thanks again Paul! Your msoFileDialogSaveAs magic did the trick. I've spent pretty much my whole morning on the MSN Developer's center reading about the the objects you used and figuring out how to integrate it into my code. (So you didn't just give me a [fish](http://www.jackspets.com/Images/Pet-Care-Information/Fish/Goldfish.png), you taught me to fish) I posted the change up top.